# Why does this "IF" always execute even the condition is false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

This is my code:

```
$('.btn-back').off('click').on('click', function (event) {
    var valid = carInfo.validate();
    if (valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

the sentence `event.preventDefault()` always executes no matter what value `valid` is.

When I change the code to

```
$('.btn-back').off('click').on('click', function (event) {
    var valid = carInfo.validate();
    if (valid) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {

    }
});
```

it runs the way it should be. Maybe it's something related to Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI).

Comment: So what is `validate` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [boolean in an if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393935/boolean-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: What does `validate()` return? It could be working on a 'truthy' value.

Comment: it won't execute if `valid` isn't true, it's more likely that your function doesn't return what you expect

Comment: Did you debug the code or had a break point on the preventDefault()? I can't believe that the first code block is not getting to preventDefault() and the second block get to it

Comment: `validate()` is my own method; right now, it returns false. When I change the code to `if (false) { event.preventDefault(); }`, the sentence event.preventDefault() always executes

Comment: Update! If I add a sentence after the "if", it works! `if (valid) { event.preventDefault(); } console.log('Hello World!');` I don't know why, but `if (valid) { event.preventDefault(); }` can't be the last sentence in the function.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`jQuery Validation`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin way:

`carInfo.validate()` will return [`Validator` object](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).

So `valid` variable is always `true`. Use `valid` method from [docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid):

```
$('.btn-back').off('click').on('click', function (event) {
    carInfo.validate();
    if (carInfo.valid()) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you need to call `validate()`?  Don't you just need `if (carInfo.valid()) {`?

Comment: `validate()` needs to be called on the form before checking it using this method. From [docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) :)

Comment: Ok, was just making sure :-)

Comment: [As per OP's comment, _"`validate()` is my own method"_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828360/why-does-this-if-always-execute-even-the-condition-is-false#comment44063167_27828360), this question is **not** about the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: I added a proposal to use jQuery validate :)

Comment: Even if it was, you would not call `.validate()` from within a `click` handler.  It's only how the plugin is _initialized_.