# Javascript boolean compare not working. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript

```js
var status = false;
status === false ? alert('Example1') : alert('Example2');
```

Can anyone please tell me why it not working as my expectation. Why it not returning Example1?

Comment: Because `window.status` already exists, and can only be a string (global properties can get [implicitly referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776759/how-to-run-code-without-implicitly-referring-to-properties-on-the-global-object) unfortunately)

Comment: [boolean in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15393935/4229270)

Comment: @Sinto The problem here is the fact that the variable is named "status", is declared with "var", and on the top level - the other question, while useful, isn't exactly applicable

Comment: He can use it if required. @CertainPerformance: anyway thanks for the response.

Comment: But why doesn't throw this error (`SyntaxError: missing variable name`) like var delete = 1;

Comment: @ﾃﾞﾋﾞｯﾄ Because `status` is not a [reserved word](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-reserved-words).