# Checking boolean truth value in Angular HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to check a Boolean values truthiness in Angular HTML, and getting an odd result. After reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15394130/1634753) I thought I understood what was happening. I expected to be able to use the === operator, but as my last example below shows, that does not return the correct result.

[StackBlitz example of my code](https://angular-gtgmby.stackblitz.io)

The output states of my code above:

**nothing selected, but default val is false**

> create new: false
>
> double eq isCreateNew==false: true
>
> string isCreateNew=='false': false <----- unexpected
>
> obj isCreateNew===false: true

**set to true create new: true**

> double eq isCreateNew==false: false
>
> string isCreateNew=='false': false
>
> obj isCreateNew===false: false

**set to false**

> create new: false
>
> double eq isCreateNew==false: false <----- unexpected
>
> string isCreateNew=='false': true
>
> obj isCreateNew===false: false <----- unexpected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only an empty string equals `false' in JS. So, the expected result is that

> string isCreateNew=='false': false

always. You can easily check this in the browser console.

Then, you don't use square brackets when binding the mat-radio-button value property. In this case, the passed value is not evaluated as JavaScript. As a result, the value of your mat-radio-button elements is a string. Not a boolean. Use square brackets to resolve other issues.

```html
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="changeAE">
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="true">set true</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="false">set false</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: nice explanation 

Answer (score 2):

As per the [type conversion rules](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), a string `'false'` does not get converted to the boolean `false`. This means that

```js
false == 'false' // It is indeed false
```

So this should not be unexpected, it is the expected result.

Now you might ask why it returns `true` when you set `isCreateNew` to `false`. The problem is actually in your code. Your radio buttons are not setting the value to boolean `false` or `true` rather it is setting it to a string. To set it to a boolean, you need to use square brackets.

```html
<mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="true">set true</mat-radio-button>
<mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="false">set false</mat-radio-button>
```

Another way to tell your value is not being set properly is by your `ngModel`. If you set `isCreateNew` to `false` in your component, it should set check the `false` radio button. Since your values are strings, this will not happen. Once you add the square brackets, you can see that the `false` radio button gets checked.

Comment: the link of **type conversion rules** is a grate hidden treasure of javascript 

Answer (score 1):

like this `value="true"` will set `changeAE` to the value of 'true' as string but this `[value]="true`" changeAE to true boolean value

```
<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="changeAE">
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="true">
      set true
    </mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" [value]="false">
      set false
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

> === is compare and  check the type of comparison sides `typeof
>   'true'` is string and `typeof true` is boolean if any of the type