# Check true or false in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I have this code:

```
function step3() {
    //finds both answers
    answer1 = top1 / (2*a);
    answer2 = top2 / (2*a);
    console.log(answer1 + " " + answer2);
    solutions = isNaN(answer1)
    console.log(solutions)
    if (solutions = true) {
        console.log("no real sol")}
    step4()
}
```

and when I run that if answer1 is NaN it does print true, but every time it prints no real sol.  Why does it do this?  I thought it would only if solutions is true.

Comment: You don't need to check a Boolean explicitly for `true` or `false`. `if(solutions)` is all you need.

Comment: `if (solutions = true)` isn't checking if `solutions` is equal to true, it is _**setting**_ `solutions` equal to `true`.  You want `if (solutions === true)` (or `==` depending on what type of equality check you want.

Comment: In addition to @ScottMarcus's comment, you're also using an assign operator (`=`) instead of an equality operator (`==`).

Comment: Learn the difference between `=` , `==` and `===`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operators `==` and `===`, so what `solutions = true` does is cause `solutions` to become `true` regardless of what it was on the prior line.

And, to check a Boolean variable, you don't need to compare it to `true` because an `if` statement will always be looking for the "true-ness" of the condition you pass, so your code should be:

```js
function step3() {
    //finds both answers
    answer1 = top1 / (2*a);
    answer2 = top2 / (2*a);
    console.log(answer1 + " " + answer2);
    solutions = isNaN(answer1)
    console.log(solutions)
    if (solutions) {
        console.log("no real sol");
    }
    step4()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS the comparison operator for checking whether two values are equal is `==` but you only have one `=` which sets the value to true, simply use

```
if(isNan(answer1)) { /*your code*/ }
```

To avoid any confusion

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all of your code but you have just one equal sign between solution and true. In comparisons we should use "==" not "="

```
function step3() {
    //finds both answers
    answer1 = top1 / (2*a);
    answer2 = top2 / (2*a);
    console.log(answer1 + " " + answer2);
    solutions = isNaN(answer1)
    console.log(solutions)
    if (solutions == true) {
        console.log("no real sol")}
    step4()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three options.

1. if (solutions)
2. if (solutions === true)
3. if (solutions == true)

This previous questions has a lot information regarding the three possibilities...
[boolean in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393935/boolean-in-an-if-statement)